# PHP MYSQL: How to add values from different columns

Tags: php

I want to multiply the values on two columns... one column is named "point" and the other "unit". i actually want to multiply values on both column and then sum the total of the multiplied values. how do i go about this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope you lookin something like this..

SELECT sum(total) FROM
(
  SELECT col1 * col2 AS total FROM your_table tbl1
) tbl2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SUM()` aggregate on a product of `point` and `unit`

```sql
SELECT SUM(point * unit) total
  FROM Table1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2819a/1)** demo